# Bind EntityFramework entities to a treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, treeview

First of all, even if I found a few similar kind of question, none (so far) answered my specific problem.

To make a quick summary, I am trying to bind data to a treeview. Here is what I have :

I have a database out of which I created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model. I want to bind 3 entities in a treeview : Country, Sector and Entity. Country (one) is linked to Entity (many) and Sector (one) to Entity (many).

Here is the code generated by the ADO.NET Entity Data Model for each of them

```
public partial class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        this.Entities = new HashSet<Entity>();
    }

    public int country_id { get; set; }
    public string country_name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}

public partial class Sector
{
    public Sector()
    {
        this.Entities = new HashSet<Entity>();
    }

    public int sector_id { get; set; }
    public string sector_name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}

public partial class Entity
{
    public Entity()
    {
        this.Entities_to_Indexes = new HashSet<Entities_to_Indexes>();
        this.StreamParameters_to_Entities = new HashSet<StreamParameters_to_Entities>();
        this.Tweets_to_Entities = new HashSet<Tweets_to_Entities>();
    }

    public int entity_id { get; set; }
    public string entity_name { get; set; }
    public int sector_id { get; set; }
    public int country_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Sector Sector { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Entities_to_Indexes> Entities_to_Indexes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StreamParameters_to_Entities> StreamParameters_to_Entities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tweets_to_Entities> Tweets_to_Entities { get; set; }
}
```

I want now to bind those to a treeview control in a WPF form in order to obtain something like this :

- Country1

  - Sector1

    - Entity1
    - Entity2
  - Sector2

    - Entity3
    - Entity4
- Country2

  - Sector1

    - Entity5
    - Entity6

....

No matter how much I look for it, I can't manage to find how to bind them straight into the Treeview.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Binding them as they are, is too damn difficult! Can't you just make an exception for `Country`->`Sector` relationship?

Comment: What's the problem? Binding the tree nodes, or creating the hierarchy from the data?

Comment: Binding would work but the data model itself does not have a hierarchical structure. I mean since Country has Entities not Sectors, the result will be different.

Comment: Thanks @Bizz, but I'd also like to here this from the OP. I always get a bit put off from OPs that don't respond to comments. My feeling is that it's about getting the hierarchy structure. I hope you didn't waste your time.

Comment: @Arnold initially, I would have said to bind the tree nodes. Reading Bizz answer, I realize its both. Make the hierarchy (solved now I guess, see comment to Bizz below) and then bind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create the view model classes as follows:

```
public class CountryVm
{
    public CountryVm(string name)
    {
        //since Name is a simple property it's better to initialize it in constructor
        //because Name is neither a dependency property nor notifies about it changes.
        //see DependencyProperty and INotifyPropertyChanged documentation
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //an observable collection notifies about any changes made in it
    public ObservableCollection<SectorVm> Sectors { get { return _sectors; } }
    private ObservableCollection<SectorVm> _sectors = new ObservableCollection<SectorVm>();
}
public class SectorVm
{
    public SectorVm(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<EntityVm> Entities { get { return _entities; } }
    private ObservableCollection<EntityVm> _entities = new ObservableCollection<EntityVm>();
}
public class EntityVm
{
    public EntityVm(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Create another viewModel for the whole window (or UserControl or whatever) I call it `MainVm` I implement two extra dependency properties as an example:

```
public class MainVm : DependencyObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a fully bindable value that indicates MyText
    /// </summary>
    public string MyText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(MainVm),
        new PropertyMetadata("default value here"));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a fully bindable value that indicates MyProp
    /// </summary>
    public float MyProp
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(MyPropProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProp", typeof(float), typeof(MainVm),
        new PropertyMetadata(0f,//default value (MUST be the same type as MyProp)
            //property changed callback
            (d, e) => 
            {
                var vm = (MainVm)d;
                var val = (float)e.NewValue;
                vm.MyText = val.ToString();
            }, 
            //coerce value callback
            (d, v) => 
            {
                var vm = (MainVm)d;
                var val = (float)v;
                //prevents from having negative value
                if (val < 0f) return 0f;
                return v;
            }));


    public ObservableCollection<CountryVm> AllCountries { get { return _allCountries; } }
    private ObservableCollection<CountryVm> _allCountries = new ObservableCollection<CountryVm>();
}
```

Set an instance of `MainVm` as the `DataContext` of your window (or UC or...)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainVm();
}
```

Set `AllCountries` as the `ItemsSource` of `TreeView`. since the `DataContext` is inherited, `DataContext` of `TreeView` is the same instance of `MainVm` you specified earlier as the `DataContext` of the window.

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding AllCountries}"/>
```

Define three resources with NO KEY so that `TreeView.ItemTemplate` automatically choose one of them based on the `DataType` of the Item.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Sectors}" DataType="{x:Type vm:CountryVm}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}" DataType="{x:Type vm:Sector}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Entity}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

also add this line to the start of your .xaml code (in Window tag). you probably have to change the namespace to your own ViewModel's namespace:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyWpfApplication1.Core.ViewModels;assembly=MyWpfApplication1.Core">
```

**Alternatively**
You can implement one ViewModel instead of three (call it TreeNodeVm)

```
public class TreeNodeVm
{
    public TreeNodeVm(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TreeNodeVm> Children { get { return _children; } }
    private ObservableCollection<TreeNodeVm> _children = new ObservableCollection<TreeNodeVm>();
}
```

and write TreeView xaml code as follows:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding AllCountries}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: As I am not sure to understand how the sectors would be populated if I just link like that the CountryVM and Sector datas, i created a view in my database that will do it. So in the end I have Country > CountriedSector > Entity 

Like this I have a Country with a collection of CountriedSectors with a collection of Entities.

Then, sorry to ask what i guess is a dumb question (did I mentionned I am a huge beginner with the MVVM concept?) but what/where is the view model of my window?

Comment: I understand, reading this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode that I am laking some key knowledge yet to fully do what I want to do (like the ViewModel). Anyway, if you can provide any help, I will take it with great pleasure

Comment: I tried to just create a class ViewModel (within a specific namespace : Twitter_NNA.EntitiesTreeview.ViewModel - its the only thing in this namespace) with the following line of code : `public ObservableCollection<Country> AllCountries { get { return _allCountries; } }
        private ObservableCollection<Country> _allCountries = new ObservableCollection<Country>();` I changed the xaml accordingly (Country insterad of CountryVm and CountriedSector instead of Sector) but I have the following errors : `vm is an undeclared namespace` / `the namespace prefix vm is not defined` and same about model

Comment: thanks for the effort. I will check it later as I don't have access to my project now. I will keep you posted of the result, even if it may take a few days. Rgds

Comment: Bizz, the code works fine. I just changed vm:Sector and vm:Entity to vm:SectorVm and vm:EntityVm. Also, it didn't want at the beginning to recognize the namespace in the xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:" line, but after adding an other xmlns (local="....") witht the same namespace it accepted it. Just had to delete then the extra line and rebuild (kind of weird but it seems other people had similar problems, even they just had to rebuild and reopen VS)

Comment: My last issue now is to understand how I can add entries to the treeview. I have all the classes set up, but i don't get how to put data in. Lets imagine a simple hierarchy like this Country1 | Sector1 | Entity1, how can i set it? I don't understand how to access to AllCountries...

Comment: AllCountries is in your MainVm, so as other properties and commands. your window has it too (as its DataContext which is needed to be cast to MainVm) so you have access in both View (window.xaml.cs) and ViewModel (MainVm)

Comment: Bizz, I tried something but it doesn't seems to work. First I am trying to do it with just one kind of class (TreeNodeVM), so I changed AllCountries to be a TreeNodeVM instead of a Country. I added a button to launch my test with this code 
`private void Pop_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                MainVM GoTest = new MainVM();
                GoTest.randomtest();
        }`
In MainVm I added a randomtest method

      `public void randomtest()
{
TreeNodeVm random = new TreeNodeVm("Why not");
AllCountries.Add(random);
}` But it doesn't show "Why not" in the Treeview.

Comment: private void Pop_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
{
    MainVM GoTest = new MainVM();
    DataContext = GoTest ...
}`

Comment: Great, thanks, I will post later a complete solution. THank you very much for the help

Comment: @samuel guedon Intetested in the complete solution!

Comment: @Contango everything is here and I must say that I am not sure anymore what I should put back together or not :/ Don't hesitate to post a precise question and I will do my best to answer. If you opened an other dedicated question,post the link, I will try to answer it